# date sorting in react component

Tags: reactjs, sorting

With this code:

```
const columns = [
    {
      title: "DATE & TIME",
      dataIndex: "scheduledTime",
      render: (scheduledTime) => <p className="mb-0">{scheduledTime}</p>,
      sorter: (a, b) => moment(a.scheduledTime).isBefore(b.scheduledTime),
      defaultSortOrder: "descend",
    },    
    {
      title: "TIMEZONE",
      dataIndex: "timezone",
      render: (timezone) => `${TIMEZONE_TZ[timezone]}`

    }]

 return (
         <Table
         columns={columns} />
)
```

There is something wrong with my sorting logic, clicking on the date should  sort them but `sorter: (a, b) => moment(a.scheduledTime).isBefore(b.scheduledTime)` doesn't seem to be working.
Here is the UI component:

[image]

In the ascending, shouldn't oct be the last entry.

[image]

Comment: are you rendering the component after sorting data.check that also. you may be rendered it at the code . you need to make that change it UI.

Comment: @ggorlen: its sorting days within the month, I need to sort it overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [docs](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/01-is-before/):

> NOTE: moment().isBefore() has undefined behavior and should not be
> used! If the code runs fast the initial created moment would be the
> same as the one created in isBefore to perform the check, so the
> result would be false. But if the code runs slower it's possible that
> the moment created in isBefore is measurably after the one created in
> moment(), so the call would return true.